# ExtJS: which values does the Ext.picker.Date accept?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

I have a `datepicker` in my form and it gets the value from the form.load in JSON format.
Which values does the datepicker support?
Because it won't bind this value:`\/Date(1241215200000)\/`.

I already have a convert function for the JSON format but I can't configure the field with a `convert` or `renderer` config.

```
convertDate = function (value) {
    if (value == null) return null;
    return new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", ""), 10));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value have to be a valid JavaScript date or `Ext.Date`. So you should bind it like

```
new Date(1241215200000)
```

For example the Newtonsoft JSON serializer is capable of returning this for a given date. But if all fails you may consider overriding the `setValue()` of the picker and apply your converter there

**Below is only valid for `Ext.field.Date`**
(*My first but wrong answer for a datepicker*)

I recommend you to use the `ISO 8601 date` format for your dates. With that you need to set the **submitFormat** to **c**

```
submitFormat: 'c'
```

Tools like **[Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/03/20/json-net-4-5-release-1-iso-dates-async-metro-build.aspx)** support the `ISO 8601 date` out of the box (and since .Net 4.5 release 1 as default).

Comment: Btw I'm using `Ext.form.field.Date` but your solution still applies :). Good suggestion overriding the setValue. Only I don't exactly know the best practice to override a class, let me make a new question for it ;)

Comment: @A1rPun OK, I will check back for that :)